# Cierre de aplicacion

Tags: android, android-studio

Cuando añado esta parte de codigo se cierra la aplicacion, el codigo funciona por que lo tengo en otra aplicacion cual puede ser el error

`WebView view = (WebView) this .findViewById (R.id.webView);
        view.getSettings (). setJavaScriptEnabled (true);
        view.setWebViewClient (new MyBrowser ());
        view.loadUrl ("http://www.google.es");
        view.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        view.setInitialScale(80);`

Comment: Esta pregunta podría considerarse como amplía, la causa porque se cierra una aplicación son diversas, si no agregas el mensaje desplegado en el  LogCat podría haber muchas posibles causas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solucionado el problema era que al ser un Fragment el codigo era distinto

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
        mWebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.es");

        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.setInitialScale(80);

        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        return v;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez no has agregado en el permiso de internet en el manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```